# How to prevent malicious pdf upload (PDF viewer cross site scripting)

Tags: pdf, upload, xss

On my website, I have a form with a file upload feature. but, it can upload malicious file pdf files to execute cross-site scripting attacks.

Referring to this pdf https://github.com/osnr/horrifying-pdf-experiments

[image]

**Any way to prevent this kind of pdf during upload.**

That pdf code

```
%PDF-1.3
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</Pages 2 0 R /Type /Catalog>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Count 1 /Kids [3 0 R] /Type /Pages>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</AA
  <</O
  <</JS
  (
try {
  app.alert\("XSS"\)
} catch \(e\) {
  app.alert\(e.message\);
}
    )
  /S /JavaScript>>>>
  /Annots [] /Contents 4 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] /Parent 2 0 R
  /Resources
  <</Font <</F1 <</BaseFont /Helvetica /Subtype /Type1 /Type /Font>>>>>>
  /Type /Page>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Length 21>>
stream

BT
/F1 24 Tf
ET
    
endstream
endobj
xref
0 5
0000000000 65535 f
0000000015 00000 n
0000000062 00000 n
0000000117 00000 n
0000000424 00000 n
trailer

<</Root 1 0 R /Size 5>>
startxref
493
%%EOF
```

Comment: I don't think there is any risk of XSS if you are just letting the user upload a PDF to your backend server, since that is just transferring bytes (nothing to do with PDF). There is only risk if you open the PDF into some application that will process it, and most PDF applications have javascript engine disabled so no JS in a PDF will ever be executed. What exactly is the issue you are trying to resolve?

Comment: Did you find solution for this pdf-xss attack? pl share